# Where to ask about Microsoft part numbers?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about the Microsoft part number that comes with Microsoft software products like Office and Windows 10.

I would like to ask what part is the number defined as? What is it useful for and what information can we derive from the part number of a Microsoft product? I want to ask from the user point of view.

Can these questions be asked on a Stack Exchange site?

*As suggested an example of the part number i'm talking about which is usually printed in the box that came with the software media (DVD, USB etc) from microsoft is something like this : [QQ2-00036] or this [QQ2-00570]

Comment: @Won't Umm i think MS does officially call it "part number" [XXX-XXXXX], because SKU is a different thing than part number according to them. SKU is more refered to in volume license.Thus I think MS FPP software products (sold in media) does come with a "part number".  I would stand corrected,. Though, I already did confirm it with them. Did you though I was using the wrong term just because you thought that it was literally wrong to call it that way?

Comment: The example definitely helps.  Can't find that example referenced anywhere as a "part number" :/

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to ask what part is the number defined as? What is it useful for and what information can we derive from the part number of a Microsoft product? I want to ask from the user point of view.

As a SU mod that seems kinda broad. *Chances* are its an entirely arbitrary code used for managing inventory and stock at retailers and to a limited extent for support purposes.

It seems more useful to start with a practical problem, than to go "What is this?" and then try to find a problem that uses a solution

Comment: And the OP then goes and asks the same question on meta.su :/ [Inquiry about topic to ask in superuser forum](//meta.superuser.com/q/12533)

Answer (score 1):

If the part number is somehow useful or necessary to using your computer-related product, it might be on topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com). Super User is our consumer-level site for computer issues, where [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) is meant more for Enterprise issues. Check their 'Help Center' (located at the top of the site) to verify.